How do I install the latest Maui workload?
Might sound like a silly question but I have faced this issue numerous times. When I go to the releases page https://github.com/dotnet/maui/releases at the time of asking the question the latest release is 8.0.92.

On my mac machine, the version installed is 8.0.82. I have tried:
(1) updating to the latest dotnet SDK (at the time of this question its 8.0.403)
brew upgrade --cask dotnet-sdk

(2) I have tried updating the workload directly
dotnet workload update

(3) uninstalling the current Maui workload, and then tried installing the maui workload
dotnet workload uninstall maui
dotnet workload install maui 
  

But, in all cases the version that is on my machine remains 8.0.82
Installed Workload Id      Manifest Version      Installation Source
maui                       8.0.82/8.0.100        SDK 8.0.400

What am I doing wrong? How do I update to the latest Maui workload?

Unrecognized command or argument 'unintall'. .... `

it's just a typo, but fixed

The version 8.0.82 is the latest, see: "The dotnet workload update command updates all installed workloads to the newest available versions. It queries Nuget.org for updated workload manifests" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-workload-update), and nuget.org

interesting, so how do i get the latest version they say in Github? https://github.com/dotnet/maui/releases

Then you need to download the source, and build it yourself. (AFAIK)

well, crap ha. could you post an answer here so I can mark it as the answer please

my main issue is that I can't hit breakpoints on a physical device, so I wanted to see if a latest build may have fixed this https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/25395

The version 8.0.82 is the latest,
see: "The dotnet workload update command updates all installed workloads to the newest available versions. It queries Nuget.org for updated workload manifests" (learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/…),
and on nuget.org (https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=maui+macos&includeComputedFrameworks=true&prerel=true&sortby=relevance) shows at the top of the searchlist: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Maui.Manifest-8.0.100 8.0.82
When you want/need the latest that is not yet available on nuget.org, you might need to build from source. (see: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/.github/DEVELOPMENT.md )
